# ReactJs + Babel - Defining components using separate files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, babeljs

Trying to create a component class with separate files

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../../assets/libs/react-0.13.3/build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/libs/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="reactive"></section>
    <script type="text/babel" src="../../components/AppBar/NavBar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      var
        reactiveNode = document.querySelector('.reactive');
      React.render( <NavBar value='hello world'/>, reactiveNode );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Navbar.js

```
var NavBar = React.createClass({
  render: function ()
  {
    return ( <h1>{this.props.value}</h1> );
  }
});
```

After run, i'm having the log:

> XHR finished loading: GET
>   "http://localhost:3000/app/components/AppBar/NavBar.js"
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: NavBar is not defined

Only works if create the class in the `index.html` file

Comment: Look for directory of Navbar.js. Is correct?

Comment: @EmirMarques yes! ajax request get the file

Comment: Change propertie value for valueH1. I believe value is reserved for ReactJs

Comment: @EmirMarques still not working

Comment: Try remove type="text/babel" from tag script

Comment: If you found your solution, either write an answer or close the question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the scope of the variable.

Solve by use

```
window.NavBar = React.createClass({
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OOP react,it should be like this

```
    class NavBar extends React.Component{
       // ...
    });
    window.NavBar = NavBar;
```